# Cannot connect to external monitors with E-Port dock station

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude, docking-station

I have an E-Port dock station and Dell Latitude E7440. I have recently switched from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1. System stopped detecting external monitor connected to my dock station.

Regardles of which port I use (VGA, DVI, DP), in the screen options in Windows the second display is always visible as `VMM2300 ROM`. It is greyed out and cannot be turned on.

When I connect the display directly to the laptop (with HDMI or HDMI -> VGA adapter) - screen is working.

Where the problem might be? I have already installed [the newest graphic drivers](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=35GXP&fileId=3377993823&osCode=WB64A&productCode=latitude-e7440-ultrabook&languageCode=EN&categoryId=VI) and visited [troubleshooting page](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN288845/EN) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to install [Synaptics VMM2320 MST HUB Firmware Update A01](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=1XFPM).

The version [A05](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=PHHTM) suggested by the [troubleshooting page](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN288845/EN) did not work for me (I could not install it).